# React navigation fail to navigate in APK build. But it works in Development Mode

Tags: react-native, apk, expo, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

I have trouble with my app.
My app has initial route to Home, then I want to navigate to other screen in HomeStackScreen eg. "Map" screen, then the app restart by itself.
The app works fine in development mode, but when it is build in the APK file, the navigation restart the app.
What I have tried,

1. navigation.navigate("Map") // fail in APK, but in development mode it works
2. navigation.navigate("Home",{screen:"Map"}) // fail in APK, but in development mode it works
3. navigation.jumpTo("Home",{screen:"Map"}) // fail in APK, but in development mode it works
4. navigation.push("Map") // fail in APK, but in development mode it works
5. navigation.replace("Map") // fail in APK, but in development mode it works
   //

> ```
> import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
> import "react-native-gesture-handler";
> import { NavigationContainer, useLinking } from "@react-navigation/native";
> import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
> import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
> //
> import Home from "./Home";
> import Map from "./Map";
> import Testimoni from "./Testimoni";
> import PasienHistory from "./PasienHistory";
> import RiwayatPenyakit from "./RiwayatPenyakit";
> import RequestTime from "./RequestTime";
> import Waiting from "./Waiting";
> import DoctorFound from "./DoctorFound";
> import Welcome from "./Welcome";
> import SignUp from "./SignUp";
> import Login from "./Login";
> import PasienBaru from "./PasienBaru";
> import VerifyCode from "./VerifyCode";
> import ListNakes from "./ListNakes";
> import RequestStatus from "./RequestStatus";
> import CustomRightHeader from "./CustomRightHeader";
> import CustomLeftHeader from "./CustomLeftHeader";
> import CustomHeaderBackHome from "./CustomHeaderBackHome";
> import CustomHeaderBack from "./CustomHeaderBack";
> import Loading from "./Loading";
> import DrawerContent from "./DrawerContent";
> import Profile from "./Profile";
> import PatientListHistory from "./PatientListHistory";
> import History from "./History";
> import HistoryDetail from "./HistoryDetail";
> import Transactions from "./Transactions";
> import TransactionDetail from "./TransactionDetail";
> import Support from "./Support";
>
> //
> import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
> import * as Location from "expo-location";
> //
> import { Vibration, Platform, View, Text } from "react-native";
> import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
> import Constants from "expo-constants";
> import * as Linking from "expo-linking";
> //redux
> import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
> import firebase from "./config/fbConfig";
> //
> import { LogBox } from "react-native";
>
> const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
> const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
> const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
> const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();
> const TransactionStack = createStackNavigator();
> const PatientListHistoryStack = createStackNavigator();
> const SupportStack = createStackNavigator();
>
> LogBox.ignoreLogs(["Setting a timer"]);
>
> const Index = () => {
>   const dispatch = useDispatch();
>   const [uid, setUid] = useState(false);
>
>   //expo-linking
>   const ref = useRef(null);
>   const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
>   const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();
>   const prefix = Linking.makeUrl("/");
>   const linkingTo = (path) => {
>     const redirectUrl = Linking.makeUrl(path);
>     return Linking.openURL(redirectUrl);
>   };
>   const { getInitialState } = useLinking(ref, {
>     prefixes: [prefix],
>   });
>   //
>   const checkLocationPermissionAsync = async () => {
>     const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
>     if (status === "granted") {
>       await Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync().then(async (service) => {
>         if (service) {
>           return true;
>         } else {
>           alert("Lokasi tidak aktif");
>           return false;
>         }
>       });
>     } else {
>       alert("Ijin lokasi tidak aktif");
>       return false;
>     }
>   };
>   const checkForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
>     if (Constants.isDevice) {
>       const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(
>         Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
>       );
>       let finalStatus = existingStatus;
>       if (existingStatus !== "granted") {
>         const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(
>           Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS
>         );
>         finalStatus = status;
>       }
>       if (finalStatus !== "granted") {
>         alert("Ijin notifikasi tidak aktif!");
>         return;
>       }
>     } else {
>       alert("Must use physical device for Push Notifications");
>     }
>
>     if (Platform.OS === "android") {
>       Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync("default", {
>         name: "default",
>         importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
>         vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
>         lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
>       });
>     }
>   };
>   const handleNotification = async (notification) => {
>     Vibration.vibrate();
>     let { identifier } = await notification.request;
>     await dispatch({ type: "NOTIFICATION", notification });
>     await linkingTo("RequestStatus");
>     setTimeout(() => Notifications.dismissNotificationAsync(identifier), 300);
>   };
>   const handleOnClickNotification = async (response) => {
>     let { notification } = response;
>     Vibration.vibrate();
>     await dispatch({ type: "NOTIFICATION", notification });
>     await linkingTo("RequestStatus");
>   };
>   const onClickNotification = async () => {
>     await Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
>       handleOnClickNotification
>     );
>   };
>   const listenNotification = async () => {
>     await Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(handleNotification);
>   };
>
>   //
>   const onLoad = async () => {
>     //expo-linking
>     await getInitialState()
>       .catch(() => {})
>       .then((state) => {
>         if (state !== undefined) {
>           setInitialState(state);
>         }
>         setIsReady(true);
>       });
>     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
>       if (user) {
>         user.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
>           if (idTokenResult.claims.patient) {
>             setUid(user.uid);
>             checkLocationPermissionAsync();
>             checkForPushNotificationsAsync();
>             listenNotification();
>             onClickNotification();
>             dispatch({ type: "OFF_LOADING" });
>           } else {
>             setUid(false);
>             dispatch({ type: "OFF_LOADING" });
>           }
>         });
>       } else {
>         setUid(false);
>         dispatch({ type: "OFF_LOADING" });
>       }
>     });
>   };
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     onLoad();
>     // return () => {
>     //   setUid(false);
>     // };
>   }, [getInitialState, uid]);
>
>   const HomeStackScreen = () => (
>     <HomeStack.Navigator
>       screenOptions={{
>         headerStyle: {
>           backgroundColor: "#29ACE3",
>         },
>         headerMode: "float",
>         headerTintColor: "#fff",
>         headerTitleStyle: {
>           fontWeight: "bold",
>           color: "#fff",
>           fontSize: 14,
>         },
>         headerTitleAlign: "center",
>         headerBackTitleVisible: false,
>         headerStatusBarHeight: 20,
>       }}
>     >
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="Home"
>         component={Home}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: "HOMECARE",
>           headerLeft: () => <CustomLeftHeader navigation={navigation} />,
>           headerRight: () => <CustomRightHeader />,
>         })}
>       />
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="Map"
>         component={Map}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: "Tentukan Lokasi Pasien",
>         })}
>       />
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="PasienHistory"
>         component={PasienHistory}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: "Pilih Pasien",
>         })}
>       />
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="PasienBaru"
>         component={PasienBaru}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: "Pasien Baru",
>         })}
>       />
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="RiwayatPenyakit"
>         component={RiwayatPenyakit}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: "Riwayat Penyakit",
>         })}
>       />
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="RequestTime"
>         component={RequestTime}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Waktu Kunjungan`,
>           headerLeft: () => <CustomHeaderBackHome navigation={navigation} />,
>         })}
>       />
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="ListNakes"
>         component={ListNakes}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Pilih Petugas`,
>           headerLeft: () => (
>             <CustomHeaderBack navigation={navigation} path={"RequestTime"} />
>           ),
>         })}
>       />
>
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="DoctorFound"
>         component={DoctorFound}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Petugas Ditemukan`,
>           headerLeft: null,
>         })}
>       />
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="Waiting"
>         component={Waiting}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           headerLeft: null,
>         })}
>       />
>       <HomeStack.Screen
>         name="RequestStatus"
>         component={RequestStatus}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Permintaan Berhasil`,
>           headerLeft: () => <CustomHeaderBackHome navigation={navigation} />,
>         })}
>       />
>     </HomeStack.Navigator>
>   );
>
>   const AuthStackScreen = () => (
>     <AuthStack.Navigator
>       screenOptions={{
>         headerStyle: {
>           backgroundColor: "#29ACE3",
>         },
>         headerMode: "float",
>         headerTintColor: "#fff",
>         headerTitleStyle: {
>           fontWeight: "bold",
>           color: "#fff",
>           fontSize: 14,
>         },
>         headerTitleAlign: "center",
>         headerBackTitleVisible: false,
>         headerStatusBarHeight: 20,
>       }}
>     >
>       <AuthStack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
>       <AuthStack.Screen
>         name="SignUp"
>         component={SignUp}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Registrasi`,
>         })}
>       />
>       <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
>       <AuthStack.Screen
>         name="VerifyCode"
>         component={VerifyCode}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Verifikasi Kode`,
>         })}
>       />
>     </AuthStack.Navigator>
>   );
>   const TransactionStackScreen = () => (
>     <TransactionStack.Navigator
>       screenOptions={{
>         headerStyle: {
>           backgroundColor: "#29ACE3",
>         },
>         headerMode: "float",
>         headerTintColor: "#fff",
>         headerTitleStyle: {
>           fontWeight: "bold",
>           color: "#fff",
>           fontSize: 14,
>         },
>         headerTitleAlign: "center",
>         headerBackTitleVisible: false,
>         headerStatusBarHeight: 20,
>       }}
>     >
>       <TransactionStack.Screen
>         name="Transactions"
>         component={Transactions}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Transaksi`,
>           headerLeft: () => <CustomLeftHeader navigation={navigation} />,
>         })}
>       />
>       <TransactionStack.Screen
>         name="TransactionDetail"
>         component={TransactionDetail}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Detail Transaksi`,
>         })}
>       />
>     </TransactionStack.Navigator>
>   );
>   const PatientListHistoryStackScreen = () => (
>     <PatientListHistoryStack.Navigator
>       screenOptions={{
>         headerStyle: {
>           backgroundColor: "#29ACE3",
>         },
>         headerMode: "float",
>         headerTintColor: "#fff",
>         headerTitleStyle: {
>           fontWeight: "bold",
>           color: "#fff",
>           fontSize: 14,
>         },
>         headerTitleAlign: "center",
>         headerBackTitleVisible: false,
>         headerStatusBarHeight: 20,
>       }}
>     >
>       <PatientListHistoryStack.Screen
>         name="PatientListHistory"
>         component={PatientListHistory}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Pilih Pasien`,
>           headerLeft: () => <CustomLeftHeader navigation={navigation} />,
>         })}
>       />
>       <PatientListHistoryStack.Screen name="History" component={History} />
>       <PatientListHistoryStack.Screen
>         name="HistoryDetail"
>         component={HistoryDetail}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           title: `Detail History`,
>         })}
>       />
>     </PatientListHistoryStack.Navigator>
>   );
>   const ProfileStackScreen = () => (
>     <ProfileStack.Navigator
>       screenOptions={{
>         headerStyle: {
>           backgroundColor: "#29ACE3",
>         },
>         headerMode: "float",
>         headerTintColor: "#fff",
>         headerTitleStyle: {
>           fontWeight: "bold",
>           color: "#fff",
>           fontSize: 14,
>         },
>         headerTitleAlign: "center",
>         headerBackTitleVisible: false,
>         headerStatusBarHeight: 20,
>       }}
>     >
>       <ProfileStack.Screen
>         name="Profile"
>         component={Profile}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           headerLeft: () => <CustomLeftHeader navigation={navigation} />,
>         })}
>       />
>     </ProfileStack.Navigator>
>   );
>   const SupportStackScreen = () => (
>     <SupportStack.Navigator
>       screenOptions={{
>         headerStyle: {
>           backgroundColor: "#29ACE3",
>         },
>         headerMode: "float",
>         headerTintColor: "#fff",
>         headerTitleStyle: {
>           fontWeight: "bold",
>           color: "#fff",
>           fontSize: 14,
>         },
>         headerTitleAlign: "center",
>         headerBackTitleVisible: false,
>         headerStatusBarHeight: 20,
>       }}
>     >
>       <SupportStack.Screen
>         name="Support"
>         component={Support}
>         options={({ navigation }) => ({
>           headerLeft: () => <CustomLeftHeader navigation={navigation} />,
>         })}
>       />
>     </SupportStack.Navigator>
>   );
>   if (!isReady) {
>     return null;
>   }
>   return (
>     <NavigationContainer
>       initialState={initialState}
>       ref={ref}
>       fallback={<Loading loading={true} />}
>     >
>       {uid ? (
>         <Drawer.Navigator
>           initialRouteName="Home"
>           drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
>         >
>           <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />
>           <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStackScreen} />
>           <Drawer.Screen
>             name="Transactions"
>             component={TransactionStackScreen}
>           />
>           <Drawer.Screen
>             name="PatientListHistory"
>             component={PatientListHistoryStackScreen}
>           />
>           <Drawer.Screen name="Support" component={SupportStackScreen} />
>         </Drawer.Navigator>
>       ) : (
>         <AuthStackScreen />
>       )}
>     </NavigationContainer>
>   );
> };
>
> export default Index;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I already has the answer.
The problem is not in react navigation but in react-native-maps.

Comment: What was the problem here?